# Seeing ourselves in the past

Tags: space

If we can see billions of light years into space how do we know we're not looking at our galaxy in the past?

Comment: We know we do. Not billions of light years, since the Milky Way is not that large, but up to a few ten thousands of light years.

Comment: I have a feeling the OP means: can we see our galaxy forming 13 billions years ago? Which would be theoretically possible if the universe is closed...